# C++ msvc compiler not type checking function parameter that's a reference

Tags: c++, visual-c++, typechecking

```cpp
enum inputs : int
{
    OPTION1,
    OPTION2
};
struct optionStr
{
    float someData;
    inputs tst;
    optionStr(inputs _in) { tst = _in; }
    optionStr() {}
};
void foo2(const optionStr& _in)
{
    printf("inputs tst: %d\n", _in.tst);
}
int main()
{
    foo2(OPTION1); // no compile time error?!
}
```

`OPTION1` is definitely not a `optionStr` yet no type error from msvc.
If I remove the constructor
`optionStr(inputs _in) { tst = _in; }`
then I get the compile time error.  Not sure what the logic is.  How would I actually get this code to actually do some type checking?

Comment: It does type checking. You have a constructor for `optionStr` that takes an `inputs`, so it can use it implicitly. Since `foo2` expect a `const`-reference, you create a temporary and pass it to `foo2`, that's perfectly valid. That's a question of implicit vs. explicit conversion, if you want `explicit` conversion, then see user7860670 answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Marking constructor with a single argument `explicit` will prevent construction of unnamed temporary in `foo2` invocation.

```
explicit optionStr(inputs _in) { tst = _in; }
```